# Commonly Used Hidden Lists or Objects

Tags: list, hidden

What are few commonly used Hidden Lists and Objects that we should know of in Sharepoint?

Comment: I asked this question as I came across History List while creating workflows using Visual Studio. Thats a hidden list which we will need to use while working with Workflows. So I was wondering if there are any other lists that I should know of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is an easy question to answer, as it depends on you definition of "commonly used" and "that we should know of".

The web part, list template and master page galleries, along with the users lists are all "hidden" lists, but they are also accessible from the site settings pages, so are they really hidden?

Comment: I asked this question as I came across History List while creating workflows using Visual Studio. Thats a hidden list which we will need to use while working with Workflows. So I was wondering if there are any other lists that I should know of.

Answer (score 1):

The best "hidden" list to me is the User Information List.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Publishing Sites there are some additional lists that are added for sharing and reusing images and content.  These are not widely understood by many since they are unique to the Publishing Features.  If you have interest in using the Publishing Features, I would dig into these.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Workflows then it is important to understand the relationship between the list where the workflow is, the relationship with the Tasks list, and the underlying Workflow data which is maintained separately.

Comment: Yes. This is is one place where I found list like 'History List' which is hidden and very useful.